# Compare Colors WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, colors, ellipse

I have some ellipsis in a canvas. I want that when I click above a ellipse it should change the color of the stroke to green, and if I click again it back to the original color that its red.

I had used this three colors.

```
SolidColorBrush red = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
SolidColorBrush green = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
SolidColorBrush transp = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
```

When I create the ellipse I already set the colors as red.

```
Ellipse obj = new Ellipse()
{
    Name = "",
    Width = width,
    Height = height,
    Fill = transp,
    Stroke = red,
};
```

Then if I click in some ellipse I ask the stroke color to change color.

```
if (obj.Stroke == red) obj.Stroke = green;
else if (obj.Stroke == green) obj.Stroke = red;
else obj.Stroke = gray;
```

But the problem is that always get in `else` condition. Even if the colors is the same in the `if` condition it returns me `false`. And always when clicked my ellipse turns gray.

Why this is happening? How can I fix?

EDIT:
[image: this <code>if</code> returns me false]

Comment: Have you tried with `obj.Stroke.Color == red.Color`?

Comment: Ary you sure that you create the `red`, `green` and `transp` brushes only once? And you may perhaps just use the predefined brushes like `Brushes.Red`, etc. instead of creating your own.

Comment: @Alberto And if I put just one `=` returns _Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Color' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'_

Comment: @Alberto If I keep `==`' returns _Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' and 'System.Windows.Media.Color'_

Comment: @Clemens I'm shure that I created just once. With `Brushes.Red` I get the same problem.

Comment: And there is no other code that sets the Stroke of an Ellipse?

Comment: @Clemens Not that I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not create your own SolidColorBrush instances, but use the predefined ones from the [Brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.aspx) class:

```
Ellipse obj = new Ellipse()
{
    Name = "",
    Width = width,
    Height = height,
    Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
    Stroke = Brushes.Red,
};

...

if (obj.Stroke == Brushes.Red)
{
    obj.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
}
else if (obj.Stroke == Brushes.Green)
{
    obj.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
}
else
{
    obj.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The stroke is `#FFFF0000` and the `Brushes.Red` is "FFFF0000" too, but returns me false. Like in the image.

Comment: Note that this code does not compare color values, but just references to brush instances. Still it should work as long as there is no other code that changes the Stroke of an Ellipse to some other brush.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably comparing different brush instances, which is why the if statement returns false. You can compare just the color instead:

```
if (((SolidColorBrush)obj.Stroke).Color == Colors.Red)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I use `(SolidColorBrush)` in the beggining, I can't set `Color` in the end. And even if I only keep the `SolidColorBrush` it returns me `false` comparing with my color.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `obj.Stroke` is clearly not `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)`... it *might* be `Brushes.Red`, or `Brushes.Green`, etc., but that's just a guess. You can find out for sure by simply putting a break point on your `if` statement.

Moving your mouse cursor over `obj.Stroke` in Visual Studio (when the break point has been hit) will tell you *exactly* what the value is and then you can simply use *that* value in your `if` statement.

Comment: I add the picture to help.